# How can I change my code to avoid recursion errors?

Tags: python, macos, recursion, memory

I'm trying to make a program that compares how long the computer takes to generate two identical random numbers at the same time when the range increases by one on every successful time. I'm going to implement a section that records the data in the future but for now the program seems to fail with the following

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (8388608, -1))
ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit
```

If the program is preventing deep recursions, I don't know how to rebuild the code to prevent recursion (I am basically a newbie to coding).

So my code is as follows:

```
import random
import time
import sys
import resource

#set the highest recursion limit
sys.setrecursionlimit(2147483617)

#change the stack size to unlimited, doesn't woork on macos
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (8388608, -1))

#These are just a counter for every attempt
ticker = 0

#This is the variable that determines the range that the random number can fall between
tick = 0

def random_number():

    #Don't know any other way to get the compare def to pull in num and num2 apart from using a global variable
    global num
    global num2

    #I commented out parts of the code that seem to break the program such as these next 3 comments
    #global tick
    #tickers()
    #tick = tick + 1
    num = random.randint (0, tick)
    num2 = random.randint (0, tick)
    return num and num2
    #del num, num2

def compare():
    global ticker
    global tick
    
    #Generate two random numbers
    random_number()

    #compare them
    while num != num2:
        ticker = ticker + 1
        #time.sleep(0.05)
        #print(ticker, 'attempts, the two guessed numbers were', num, '&', num2)
        #del num, num2
        compare()
    else:
        #time.sleep(0.05)
        tick = tick + 1
        print (ticker, 'attempts when guessing between',tick, 'numbers. Number found. It is', num)
        ticker = 0
        compare()



compare()
```

Some of the comments are just parts of the code that seem to break it.

I was expecting it to just keep giving me results like this infinitely for me to set a break point later:

```
2 attempts when guessing between 7 numbers. Number found. It is 6
14 attempts when guessing between 8 numbers. Number found. It is 4
6 attempts when guessing between 9 numbers. Number found. It is 3
23 attempts when guessing between 10 numbers. Number found. It is 3
28 attempts when guessing between 11 numbers. Number found. It is 7
2 attempts when guessing between 12 numbers. Number found. It is 4
```

Commenting out sys.setrecursionlimit() gets the program to work as intended for a while and display results like just above until it reaches a range of about 240 and it says that python quit due to the recursion limit being reached.

I have made some attempts to increase the recursion limit and increase the stack size but macOS seems to restrict doing that. Instead of raising the limits, is there a way to better write my code to avoid running into recursion to avoid the problem entirely? Sorry if it's painfully obvious to you what I'm doing wrong, I'm pretty new to these types of problems.

Comment: This is not a recursive problem.  This is an iterative problem.  Change the recursion to a `while True:` loop, and you should achieve success.

Comment: `return num1 and num2` does not do what you think it does.  That does a Boolean `and` of those two values.  You want `return num1, num2`, BUT even that won't work unless you call it with `num, num2 = random_number()`.  You don't need globals.